# Cognos Report Studio: Display search terms and options from select and search prompt in a report

Tags: javascript, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-8

Is it possible to display the search terms and option selected by the user from a select and search prompt?

### Ideally the customer wants to enter these on a prompt page and then have them displayed in the report output.

Further Detail:

The customer wants to be able to see what the user searched for rather than the values passed to the parameter.

For example, in the case of a Select and Search Prompt:

E1243 English & Drama Studies

a.  The user types ‘English’ in the Select and Search Prompt
b.  The search would return any value containing ‘English’
c.  The user then selects the value ‘English & Drama Studies’ which is passed to the paramater
d.  The customer wants to display the text entered into the Select and Search box rather than the paramDisplaValue

Does this make sense?

Any help much appreciated even if it's to say this isn't possible.

--

Does anyone have any suggestions for a javascript based solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add Text component and set Source Type of it to Report Expression. Add

```
ParamDisplayValue('p_YouParameter')
```

as report Expression

Comment: Thanks for the reply but in this case the customer wants to be able to see what the user searched for rather than the values passed to the parameter.  I've added some more detail to the original question.

Comment: In this case there is no automatic solution AFAIK. You can build something custom on Javascript and hidden parameter.